# How to select columns programmatically in a data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following data.table (DT):

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = 1:3, V2 = 4:6, V3 = 7:9)
```

I would like to select a subset of the variables programmatically (dynamically), by using an object where the relevant variable names are stored. For example, I want to select the two columns "V1" and "V3" stored in a variable "keep"

```
keep <- c("V1", "V3")
```

If we were to select the "keep" columns from a data.frame, the following would work:

```
DT[keep]
```

Unfortunately, this is not working when this is a data.table. I thought the data.frame and data.table are identical with this kind of behavior, but apperently they aren't. Anybody able to advise on the correct syntax?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is covered in [FAQ 1.1, 1.2 and 2.17](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html).

Some possibilities:

```
DT[, keep, with = FALSE]
DT[, c('V1', 'V3'), with = FALSE]
DT[, c(1, 3), with = FALSE]
DT[, list(V1, V3)]
```

The reason `DF[c('V1','V3')]` works as it does for a `data.frame` is covered in `` ?`[.data.frame` ``

> Data frames can be indexed in several modes. When `[` and `[[` are used
>   with a single vector index (`x[i]` or `x[[i]]`), they index the data frame
>   as if it were a list. In this usage a `drop` argument is ignored, with a
>   warning.

---

From [`data.table 1.10.2`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v1102--on-cran-31-jan-2017), you may use the `..` prefix when subsetting columns programmatically:

> When `j` is a symbol prefixed with `..` it will be looked up in calling scope and its value taken to be column names or numbers [...] It is experimental.

Thus:

```
DT[ , ..keep]
#    V1 V3
# 1:  1  7
# 2:  2  8
# 3:  3  9
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more possibilities:

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = keep]
DT[, mget(keep)]
```

Comment: I'm glad `mget()` works this way, but I am maybe a little confused on how data.table handles this. Say I want to do it dynamically: `dt2[,names(dt1)]` just returns the equivalent of `names(dt1)` (a list of column names in dt1), but `dt2[,mget(names(dt1))]` will return the subset of `dt2` (as in the data.table object, columns and rows) with those column names (unless one of the columns in `dt1` is not in `dt2`, in which case it throws `Error: value for ‘missing_column’ not found`). I just find it curious.